# Multiple Currency Pairs returned in Single API Call

Tags: api, websites, website-integration

Does anyone know where can I find an API that outputs an array of cryptocurrencies (BTC, ETH, LTC, etc.) converted to USD?

For Example:

www.somesite.com/api/rest/baseCurrency=USD

Returns:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "BTC": {
            "Id": "1231",
            "Name": "Bitcoin",
            "CurrentAsk": "4481.01"
        },
        "ETH": {
            "Id": "3242",
            "Name": "Etherium",
            "CurrentAsk": "322.09"
        },
        "LTC": {
            "Id": "4354",
            "Name": "Litecoin",
            "CurrentAsk": "73.57"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware that I can make multiple API calls to get this information, but would rather retrieve the information I'm looking for in a single call.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liqui has an excellent API for currency pairs, and most importantly multiple currency pairs. Documentation can be found [here](https://liqui.io/api).

[Here](https://api.liqui.io/api/3/ticker/btc_usdt-eth_usdt-ltc_usdt?ignore_invalid=1) is an example call that will produce calls for the following currency pairs (using USDt):

- BTC -> USD
- ETH -> USD
- LTC -> USD

Sample output:

```
{
    "btc_usdt": {
        "high": 4600.0,
        "low": 3956.08280896,
        "avg": 4278.04140448,
        "vol": 712485.2240255205420855,
        "vol_cur": 168.99447489,
        "last": 4379.41785788,
        "buy": 4379.41785787,
        "sell": 4413.6739016,
        "updated": 1504647325
    },
    "eth_usdt": {
        "high": 340.05294292,
        "low": 274.50728822,
        "avg": 307.28011557,
        "vol": 688282.534710083298132,
        "vol_cur": 2250.19082593,
        "last": 318.36785145,
        "buy": 316.78625466,
        "sell": 319.32561326,
        "updated": 1504647325
    },
    "ltc_usdt": {
        "high": 75.0,
        "low": 63.34554099,
        "avg": 69.172770495,
        "vol": 99844.7364654590349569,
        "vol_cur": 1466.92135471,
        "last": 72.00000001,
        "buy": 71.89356482,
        "sell": 72.46986363,
        "updated": 1504647325
    }
}
```